# Datagridview row height issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I recently updated my code from using `Rows.Add` in a foreach loop to using `AddRange` with populated `list of rows`. This has proven to increase the speed of populating the datagridview (significantly), but I'm having issues with the row height. This was not an issue with `Rows.Add` as I could easily just set the `rowtemplate.height` property. Parts of the event:

```
var items = listItems; int count = 1;
object[] buffer = new object[3];
List<DataGridViewRow> rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

foreach (var i in items)
{
buffer[0] = count;
buffer[1] = i.Desc;
buffer[2] = i.ID;

rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
rows[rows.Count - 1].CreateCells(datagridItems, buffer);
count++;
}
datagridItems.Rows.AddRange(rows.ToArray());
```

For whatever reason, whatever the `rowtemplate.height` property is set to, it doesn't matter when adding rows this way. I'm pretty sure it has to do with this `rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());`, because if I try to add this just before the `AddRange`:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in rows)
    {
        r.MinimumHeight = 46;
        r.Height = 46;
    }
```

^ it works. However I don't think this a good way of doing it. So I've tried to play around with the `new DataGridViewRow()`, but with no success thus far:

```
var items = listItems; int count = 1;
object[] buffer = new object[3];
List<DataGridViewRow> rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

foreach (var i in items)
{
buffer[0] = count;
buffer[1] = img;
buffer[2] = i.ID;

//rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow()); From the old example   
rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow
{
    MinimumHeight = 46,
    Height = 46
});
rows[rows.Count - 1].CreateCells(datagridItems, buffer);
count++;   
}

/* this works, but there should be a much better way of doing it
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in rows)
{
    r.MinimumHeight = 46;
    r.Height = 46
}
*/
datagridItems.Rows.AddRange(rows.ToArray());
```

And for the record, these are some of the (maybe) relevant properties set on the datagridview

```
//by the way, the datagridview is added in the designer
datagridItems.RowTemplate.Height = 46;
datagridItems.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
datagridItems.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
datagridItems.RowTemplate.MinimumHeight = 46;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DataGridView.RowTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#remarks) is useful for cases that you do not explicitly add a `DataGridViewRow` and you just set data source or pass the values or pass the row count. In your case, since you are creating the rows yourself, it's your responsibility to configure the row's properties manually, or create the rows by cloning the template manually.

In all the following examples `RowTemplate` property will be automatically used to create the row:

- `dataGridView1.DataSource = myList;`
- `dataGridView1.RowCount = 5;`
- `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(3);`
- `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[]{1, "One"});`
- `dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, new object[]{1, "One"});`

If you add a row like this `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(myNewRow)`, you have to take care of the `myNewRow` properties yourself, for example:\

- `var myNewRow = new DataGridViewRow() {Height = 50};`

Or you can create `myNewRow` by cloning the `RowTemplate`, for example:

- `var myNewRow = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Clone();`

You may learn more by tracing the usages, in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,259dd5ac24ecdfac,references) of the `RowTemplate` property.